# Accessing private method from different instance of the same class

Tags: java, oop, installation, instance-variables, access-modifiers

I just came across a code.In one case i am not able to access the private members of the class using its instance (which is fine) but in other case i am able to access the private members with its different instance (belongs to the same class). Can anyone please explain me why its happening?

```
 class Complex {
    private double re, im; 
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + re + " + " + im + "i)";
    }
    Complex(){}

/*Below c is different instance, still it can access re,im( has a private access) 
  without any error.why? */

    Complex(Complex c) {
        re = c.re;
        im = c.im;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Complex c1 = new Complex();
        Complex c2 = new Complex(c1);
        System.out.println(c1.re);  /* But getting an error here , 
        which is expected as re and im has a private access in Complex class.*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Because that's how Java works? "Otherwise, the member or constructor is declared private, and access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor." (JLS 6.6.1) Access control is by class, not instance, in Java. (protected is slightly tricksy in that respect, admittedly.)

Answer (score 5):

You can access private members from *any* code block that is defined in the *same class*. It doesn't matter what the instance is, or even if there is any instance (the code block is in a static context).

But you cannot access them from code that is defined in a *different class*.

Your first reference is in the same class, `Complex`, which is why it works. And the second is in a different class, `Main`, which is why it doesn't work.

Comment: If i don't want the field to be accessed by a different instance of the same class, how can i do it? To be clearer, what i'm asking for is something like `private[this]` in Scala

Comment: AFAIK not possible in Java. I don't see the importance of that, anyway: to me encapsulation is about code (and ownership of it), not runtime instances.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is class `Main` cannot access to private fields of other classes. In this case to the private fields of `Complex` class.
You can access to private fields in `Complex` class only from methods in this class. In other words, if you move `main` method to `Complex` class the code will be compiled.
If you want to get/set values in `Complex` class from `Main` (or other classes) you should add setters/getters in `Complex` class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the table explaining access modifiers:

[image]

As you can see, in the `private` row, everything is `N` except for the column `Class`. That means you can access private members as long as you are accessing them in the same class as they are declared. You can even access private non-static members from a static context in the same class using an instance. There is no access modifier that only allows access from the same instance.

Why?

Because figuring out whether `this` and `c` are the same instance at compile time is a pain. You have to actually run the code to see if they are referring to the same instance or not.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually the access specifiers are @ class level, not @ instance level.

Following could be the reasons to keep access specifiers @ class level.
From [JLS Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6), we can clearly see that the access is for users, who are implementing(or using a class/package) based on the contract.

To put in simple terms, as a developer(users) all I am concerned is what are the members(variables,methods) available, and what they do, how I can use them(the base of abstraction concept).

In your case, it is the same class and it has all the privilege to access its member and hence the observed behaviour.